# Login screen - button to next segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I've looked at and viewed other methods but didn't find one to do what I want and the ones that do carry out the task don't work for me.

I have 3 fields, all which require data to be entered to proceed to the next view, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my code so far;

```
@IBOutlet weak var campustext: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var usernametext: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordtext: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var loginlabel: UILabel!


@IBAction func loginbutton(sender: AnyObject){
    var campus = "Magee"
    var username = "B00123456"
    var password = "Password"

    if  campustext.text == campus &&
        usernametext.text == username &&
        passwordtext.text == password
    {
       let segueShouldOccur = true
    }         
    else           
    {
        loginlabel.text = "Oops..something went wrong. Please try again."
        println("Credentials were not correct")
        let segueShouldOccur = false  
    }
}

override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String!, sender: AnyObject!) -> Bool {
    if identifier == "mainview" {
        // perform your computation to determine whether segue should occur
        let segueShouldOccur = true || false // you determine this
        if !segueShouldOccur {
            let notPermitted = UIAlertView(title: "Alert", message: "Segue not permitted (better message here)", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")

            // shows alert to user
            notPermitted.show()

            // prevent segue from occurring
            return false
        }
    }

    // by default perform the segue transition
    return true
}
```

If anyone can help, would really appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure you ask a clear question and provide only relevant code. Also, mention both desired and observed behavior if applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Use `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

If the login details are correct, call `performSegueWithIdentifier`. Otherwise, don't call it.

`shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` will not actually initiate any segues.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually performing any segue in your code.
There are 2 possible solutions for your problem:

1. `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` can prevent a segue from being performed. Transfer the validation code from `loginbutton` to this method and connect the login button to a segue via the storyboard.

OR
2. Remove `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` and add a call to `performSegueWithIdentifier` in `loginbutton` when the the validation passes

Either way your should still create a Segue in your storyboard. Either from the ViewController (and give it an identifier) or straight from the login button